# Order List Using Caml Query in a text field as a number on SP 2010

Tags: 2010, caml-query, ssom

How can I order a Column where the type is text, but all the values stored are numeric,

I want to order it descending but considering the Column a Numeric field without changing the column type

Thank you

Comment: Even as text, numbers are treated correctly for purposes of ordering.

Comment: so, should I only change the Type to "numeric" instead of text in the camlquery ? <Value Type='Text'>  , cause currently my results are in the following order: 1,11,19,2,20,3,30

Comment: The trick is to add leading 0’s.  01,02,03...10,11,12.  If it gets to the 100’s, you’ll need to add 2 leading 0’s.  001,002,003...010011,012...100.  Keep the type of ‘text’

Comment: I think i'll go with a calculated column as we can't modify the column data. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So This was my solution :

I created a Calculated column based on the original column with output type as numeric

There was a problem though. the calculated column at the beginning was returning the result as text too.

To fix this issue I had to do the following :

> 1.- ad a +"0" to the formula

I don't know how or why this worked, but doing this it transformed all the items into numeric.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using CAML.

You'd need to fetch the results then sort using JavaScript.